# Discrete Fourier Transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis

Assuming I have a function $f(x)$. I can use a numerical Fourier transformation:

```
NFourierTransform[]
```

to find some points of $F(\omega)$. How can I do the same when I have not $f(x)$ but some points of it, i.e. $f(x_i)$.

For example:

```
PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]
f[x_] := E^(-(x^2/2))/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
Testdata = Array[f, 100, {-2, 2}];
```

`Fourier[Testdata]` gives a complex dataset back, but the Fourier transform should be again a real Gaussian?

Comment: Did you look at `Fourier`?

Comment: Yep, I tried that, but the outcome was totally different than the numerical Fourier transformation of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gaussian `f[x]` you are transforming is given by your PDF statement. The corresponding frequency-domain Gaussian is given by

```
FourierTransform[f[x], x, w]
```

which is the same function with `w` replacing `x`, that is, `f[w]`. The discrete Fourier transform on numerical data, implemented by `Fourier`, assumes periodicity of the input function. Hence, the `Testdata` you supply is seen by `Fourier` as a function of the following form, with an infinite number of peaks ranging from minus infinity to infinity.

```
Testdata = Array[f, 100, {-2, 2}];
ListLinePlot[Join[Testdata, Testdata, Testdata], Frame -> True, 
             DataRange -> {-150, 150}]
```

[image: test data]

Note that the function does not reach zero, as an actual Gaussian would (in the limit). This offset means that you are not actually transforming a Gaussian function when you input `Testdata` to `Fourier`. A better approximation would be to sample more of the tails of the true Gaussian. In addition, with your `Array` formulation, the replications assumed by `Fourier` cause a double-sampling the points at `f[-2]` and at `f[2]`. It is better to match endpoints so that, when replicated, the (approximate) Gaussians match seemlessly. The following table of `f[x]` extends the range to better sample the tails, matches endpoints, and centres on zero (the first sample).

```
TestdataFull = RotateRight[Table[f[x], {x, -5.0, 5.0 - 1.0/10., 1.0/10.}], 50];
ListLinePlot[TestdataFull, Frame -> True]
```

[image: better test data]

`Fourier` returns complex data even if the input signal is real. However, by matching endpoints and sampling the Gaussian more fully, the imaginary part is now essentially noise.

```
GraphicsRow[{
   ListLinePlot[Re[Fourier[TestdataFull]][[Range[20]]], 
           PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Real Component"],
   ListLinePlot[Im[Fourier[TestdataFull]][[Range[20]]], 
           PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Imaginary Component"]}]
```

[image: fourier transform]

Take the magnitude of the complex, yet essentially real, data returned by Fourier, and centre the peak. There's your real Gaussian.

```
ListLinePlot[RotateRight[Abs[Fourier[TestdataFull]], 50], 
             PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```